# Erro no atributo "rowkey" do DataTable - JSF 2.2 com PrimeFaces 6.2

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Sou iniciante em JSF e estou tendo problema no atributo `rowkey` do DataTable.

Ele simplesmente não consegue achar a referência que eu coloquei do meu atributo `var`. É como se o nome que eu coloquei no `var` só servisse para os componentes que estão dentro do DataTable (`<p:column>`). Segue o código:

```xml
<p:datatable var="p" value="#{controller.listaExemplo}"
 selection="#{controller.linhaSelecionada}" selectionMode="single" rowkey="#{p.id}">
    <p:column ....................
</p:datatable>
```

Antes mesmo de eu iniciar o servidor para testar, a IDE mesmo já avisa que a linha do `rowkey` não consegue achar a referência que eu coloquei.

Eu procurei muito e não achei ninguém com esse mesmo problema que o meu, procurei na documentação do primefaces e também não achei nada a respeito.

O que devo fazer? O que fiz de errado?

Comment: Você usa p.id em alguma coluna?

Comment: @AntonioSantos Uso, nas colunas a referencia ao "var" funciona normalmente mas dentro da tag <p:datatable> não, e todos os exemplos, até o oficial no site do primefaces, usam o "rowkey" da maneira que eu estou tentando e funciona, pelo menos eu acho q funciona pq se não eles não iriam mostrar isso como exemplo...

Comment: Como está o objeto? Existe o getId() no objeto ou ele fica em uma interface?

Comment: @MarcusMartins Existe sim um getId() publico e que retorna o Id do objeto que é unico, retorna um long pq no banco de dados este id é do tipo bigint, e mesmo assim o rowKey não consegue encontrar ele, nn consegue pegar a referencia que eu nomeei no atributo var. Mas tem uma coisa que eu percebi, quando eu crio uma tag <p:datatable> e ja fecho ela (assim `<p:datatable .../>`) o rowKey consegue pegar a referencia do var mas se eu abro a tag (assim `<p:datatable > ... </p:datatable>`) o rowKey não consegue mais pegar a referencia. (obs: desculpe pela demora para responder)

Comment: @Bruno você está usando o nome rowkey, ou foi só um erro quando você digitou, pois sempre coloco **rowKey**="{p.id}".

Comment: > @Bruno você está usando o nome rowkey, ou foi só um erro quando você digitou, pois sempre coloco **rowKey**="{p.id}". – MiguelCPJava 24/08 às 18:53 (obs: foi mal pela demora para responder...) @MiguelCPJava não é um erro de digitação eu estou digitando certo `rowKey="#{categorias.idCategoria}"` não sei porque esta dando este erro mas não é por erro de digitação, tanto que eu baixei o projeto do PrimeFaces que ele apresenta la no Showcase e estava dando o mesmo erro que o meu, sem falar que no pc dos meus amigos tbm da o msmo erro mas na internet não achei ninguem com esse mesmo problema que